# Does anyone know how to disable directory browsing in websphere 7?

Tags: java, websphere

We have leveraged some security tools to scan our application in websphere. A Directory Listing problem exists. Does anyone know how to disable directory browsing in websphere?

Thanks,
Joseph

Comment: Find it. In the file ibm-web-ext.xmi, you could set to false the directoryBrowsingEnabled property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find it. In the file ibm-web-ext.xmi, you could set to false the directoryBrowsingEnabled property.